# How to change image path to image tag?

Tags: php, regex

I just want to regex the image in php, while fetching the data if found any image it's directely change in image tag like:`anyimage.jpg` changes to `<img src="anyimage.jpg" alt="somthing"/>`
how is it possible.

Comment: Please add input .expected output and attempts.

Comment: why do you want to use regexp for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\S+\.jpg)
```

Try this.Replace by `<img src="$1" alt="somthing"/>`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/11

```
$re = "/(\\S+\\.jpg)/mi";
$str = "anyimage.jpg";
$subst = "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"somthing\"/>";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```